# Modify Subreport Query in Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

How can I change the query of a subreport using Java?

```
JasperDesign subREPORT = JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\src\\reports\\voted.jrxml");
JRDesignQuery subnewQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
String subsqlmm = "select * from registration where student_no='07005' order by lastname";
subnewQuery.setText(subsqlmm);
subREPORT.setQuery(subnewQuery);

JasperDesign REPORT = JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\src\\reports\\statistics.jrxml");
JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
String sqlmm = "SELECT * from profile";
newQuery.setText(sqlmm);
REPORT.setQuery(newQuery);
JasperReport JAS_REP = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(REPORT);
JasperPrint JAS_PRINT = JasperFillManager.fillReport(JAS_REP, null,conn);
JasperViewer.viewReport(JAS_PRINT, false);
```